# Call same service multiple times at the same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `$http` service (or factory).

```
angular.module("app")
    .factory("PriceService", function ($http) {
        return {
            get: function (item) {
                var url = "/pricing";

                return $http.post(url, item);
            }
        }
    });
```

I am reading items from an Excel file. And each item will call the service once.

```
for (item in excelItems) {
    console.time(item.referenceId);
    PriceService.get(item).then(function(response) {
        console.timeEnd(item.referenceId);
        // process result
    }, function() {
        // error
    })
}
```

The for loop finishes instantly, so all items should call `PriceService` almost at the same time. However, it seems that the items are calling the service one after another. Please see the console time results (the left column is refereceId).

```
    3: 2283.264ms
    5: 3167.943ms
    2: 3327.372ms
    11: 3767.073ms
    12: 3849.267ms
    14: 5388.853ms
    8: 15996.263ms
    16: 16636.952ms
    4: 17689.306ms
    18: 18190.733ms
    15: 19323.512ms
    20: 20009.020ms
    13: 23326.644ms
    10: 23378.259ms
    22: 24077.294ms
    24: 24568.147ms
    total: 24570.348ms
```

Is there any way that I can improve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If i understand right your asking to run things at the same time? If so JavaScript is single threaded. Nothing will ever happen at the same time as something else.

Comment: @ste2425 Thanks. Do you have any suggestion on improving this?

Comment: Not overly. You just making a network call so you will have the delay in involved in networking. Your logging after you get the response back, your not taking into account your processing after the fact. You could make micro optimizations on the client but if you have performance issues it appears here everything is happening on the server.

Comment: What did make you think that they are called one after another? PriceService is called instantly but may *end* one after another if the server can't handle the requests simultaneously. Check network tab for more information.

Comment: It's impossibile to execute every request at the same time. Javascript it's single threaded.

Comment: What does your PriceService look like? Can the resource you are calling accept the whole array of items instead of passing them one at a time? Can you add a server side middle tier (maybe Java which is multi-threaded?) that accepts an array in a single request and then makes the calls simultaneously? Just some thoughts.

Comment: @ste2425 Thanks again. I guess we have to make some improvements in the back end.

Comment: @ShaunScovil Thank you! The mid tier service right now takes only one object at one time. We are working on that mid tier takes an array of 10 objects at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different approach.
If every request is idempotent you can use the $q module by this way:

```
var promises = [];
for (item in excelItems) {
    promises.push(PriceService.get(item));
}
$q.all(promises).then(function(results){
    //Ok
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a nice alternative. We have decided to make some improvements in the mid tier.